# Firebase Functions onCreate not triggering

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having problems with the onCreate trigger. It is not been called. Here is my code:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/mycollection/{id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const a = snapshot.val();
  return admin.firestore().doc('other/'+a.id).set({
    // data...
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('Successfully created other');
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error creating other:', error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Which Firebase database product are you working with?  Firestore or Realtime Database?  Your code is currently triggering on Realtime Database, but querying Firestore.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: That's right Doug. Changing to firestore fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are mixing-up a Cloud Function trigger for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) with a trigger for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). They are two different NoSQL Database services offered by Firebase.

`exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref(...).onCreate(...)` is for declaring a trigger for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data), but you define it to be triggered when a document (or node) is added to `'/mycollection/{id}'` which leads me to believe that you want to implement a [trigger for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created).

If this assumption is correct, you should do as follows:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('/mycollection/{id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

      // perform desired operations ...

    });
```

Comment: Thank you Renaud. Worked perfectly!